# Secure data transfer over HTTP when HTTPS is not an option

Tags: http, https, cgi, remote-access

I would like to write an application to **manage files, directories and processes** on **hundreds of remote PCs**. There are measurement programs running on these machines, which are currently managed manually using TightVNC / RealVNC. Since the number of machines is large (and increasing) there is a need for automatic management. The plan is that our operators would get a scriptable client application, from which they could send queries and commands to server applications running on each remote PC.

For the communication, I would like to use a TCP-based custom protocol, but it is administratively complicated and would take very long to open pinholes in every firewall in the way. Fortunately, there is a program with a built-in TinyWeb-based **custom web server running on every remote PC**, and port 80 is opened in every firewall. These web servers serve requests coming from a central server, by starting a CGI program, which loads and sends back parts of the log files of measurement programs.

So the  plan is to write a **CGI program**, and communicate with it from the clients through **HTTP** (using GET and POST). Although (most of) the remote PCs are inside the corporate intranet, they are scattered all over the country, **I would like to secure the communication**. It would not be wise to send commands, which manipulate files and processes, in plain text. **Unfortunately the program which contains the web server cannot be touched, so I cannot simply prepare it for HTTPS. I can only implement the security layer in the client and in the CGI program.  What should I do?**

I have read all similar questions in SO, but I am still not sure what to do in this specific situation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you tunneling the VNC connections over SSH? Perhaps you could also tunnel the HTTP connection?

Comment: Does the Web server support executing scripts or other programs when certain HTTP resources are accessed, in a similar way to PHP or Perl scripts?

Comment: @steveax We use SSH tunneling only in those few cases when the remote PC is not inside the corporate intranet.

Comment: @PeterO. The web server is only able to run executable CGI programs. The existing CGI programs are written in Delphi. PHP, Perl etc. are not installed, and I would avoid installing them because writing and distributing a CGI exe is much simpler, than installing and configuring these scripting environments on hundreds of remote PCs...

Comment: couldn't you handle encryption and decryption in you cgi program (and clients)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several webshells but as far as I can see ( http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/features.html ) they run on the top of an existing SSL/TLS layer.

There is also [S-HTTP](http://www.javvin.com/protocolHTTPS.html).

There are several ways of authenticating to an server (username/passwort) in a protected way, without SSL. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/secure-authentication-without-ssl-using-javascript . But these solutions are focused only on sending a username/password to the server.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I will check out these options (and maybe wait for other answers too) before accepting your answer.

Comment: Btw, its an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to implement something like message-level security in SOAP/WS-Security? I realise this might be a bit heavy duty and complicated to implement, but at least it is

- standardised
- definitely secure
- possibly supported by some libraries or frameworks you could use
- suitable for HTTP